# Python beautifulsoup search issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having issues having bs find this text. I think it's because the text on the page has extra quotes around it. I was told it's because the class is actually blank.  If that's the case, then any suggestions on how I can build my search?
Actual text on website: `<span class="" data-product-price="">`

My code (I've tried several variations): `soup.find_all('span',{'class' : '" data-product-price="'})`

I've also tried just doing a regular search, but I'm not doing that correctly.  Any suggestions or should I use something other than bs?

Edited to include full code:

```
    import bs4
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r=requests.get('https://www.gouletpens.com/products/twsbi-diamond-580- 
    fountain-pen-clear?variant=11884892028971')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
    print(soup)     
    #soup.find_all('span',{'class' : '" data-product-price="'})
    #soup.find_all('span',{'class' : 'data-product-price'})[0].text
```

Comment: I think it is because the class is empty. You can't see it but the text on the website is the following: `<span class="" data-product-price="">`

Comment: _Actual text on website:_ Did you forget to include the text? Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: @Andrej Kesely This is the URL: https://www.gouletpens.com/products/twsbi-diamond-580-fountain-pen-clear?variant=11884892028971

Comment: @Boendal I'm not sure why it didn't show up, but I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at URL, you can select the price with CSS selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.gouletpens.com/products/twsbi-diamond-580-fountain-pen-clear?variant=11884892028971'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('span[data-product-price]').get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
$50.00
```

---

**OR:** with `bs4` API (set `{'data-product-price':True}` to search tags with this attribute regardless of value in it:

```
print(soup.find('span', {'data-product-price':True}).get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked perfectly. Now I know what I need to spend more time learning. I really appreciate your help.